# android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException Inside new thread

Tags: java, android, sockets

In my activity i have the following code:

```
 mChannel= new SignalChannel();
    mChannel.run();
```

SignalChannel is a class which extends thread as follows:

```
package com.eddieharari.poker5o;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class SignalChannel extends Thread {
    public boolean StopMe = false;
    private AppConstants mAppConstants = new AppConstants();
    private Socket mSocket;
    private String mServer = mAppConstants.ServerIP;
    private int mPort = mAppConstants.SignalPort;
    private Logger mLogger = new Logger();
    private InetAddress ServerIP;
    private PrintWriter mPrintWriter;
    private BufferedReader mBufferedReader;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            ServerIP = InetAddress.getByName(mServer);
            mSocket = new Socket(mServer, mPort);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Yet - Still getting the error:

j

```
ava.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.eddieharari.poker5o/com.eddieharari.poker5o.LobbyActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1565)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:389)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:230)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:212)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:436)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:621)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:570)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:450)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:218)
        at com.eddieharari.poker5o.SignalChannel.run(SignalChannel.java:27)
        at com.eddieharari.poker5o.LobbyActivity.onCreate(LobbyActivity.java:38)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
```

I am trying to figure out why is my networking is considered on the main thread , i am opening a new thread for that networking operations.

thanks ,

Eddie.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call `mChannel.run();` no new thread is started but your code actually runs on the main thread. You need to call `mChannel.start();` instead for the JVM to properly create a separate thread.

Answer (score 3):

You start a thread using `YourThreadClass.start()` and that will automatically execute what's in your `run()` method on a separate thread.